# What happens in the subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to understand a piece of code related with communication. I want to know the meaning of following line of code:

```
kwargs["stdout"] = subprocess.PIPE
```

Comment: That's just assigning an integer value (`subprocess.PIPE`, which happens to be equal to `-1`) to a dictionary key.  By itself it doesn't really have anything to do with the `subprocess` module. When used as an argument to `subprocess.run` or other methods, the value of `subprocess.PIPE` has special meaning when used as the value of the `stdout`, `stderr`,  and `stdin` parameters. See the `subprocess` documentation for more details.

Comment: The docs that @larsks mention: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Understood ! Thanks @larks